Electron dialog.showOpenDialog doesn't respect filters on Linux
I want to filter when choose a file with showOpenDialog on Electron.
I would like to make user able to choose Markdown (md) only.
But it is not respected.
So now User can select a file of all type.
How I can fix it?
My environment is:
ArchLinux
GNOME 46.2
Electron 31.0.1
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("node:path");
const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
    return win;
}
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = createWindow()
    ipcMain.handle('FileChooser', async () => {
        const res = await dialog.showOpenDialog(win, { properties: ["openFile"], title: "Select a Markdown", filters: { name: "Markdown", extensions: ["md"] } })
        return res;
    })
})


The filters option takes an array of filters. You are not passing an array, you are passing a single filter object.
Wrap the object in [] so you pass an array with one filter object inside.
